# How to apply Integer Count in items TextView In ListView When add new Item to add value In Firebase Database

Tags: android

I m Creating a `Listview` in `Firebase Database`.
And want to Count the Integer value in items in listview when I added a new Item.

I,m creating the Teachers Salary data and want to when to add a new item 
As Below...

Teacher Name, Teacher Total Salary, Teacher Total Student

But I want to count every teacher's Total Salary in 1 Textview when I added the new Teacher then add the Salary of all teachers in 1 TextView.

(Note) I don't want to count of the item I added in listview I want to count off every teacher salary if anyone can help how I can do this.

please share your Code.
Thank you in advance.

[Here is screenshot want to count the salary i have not created any code because i do not khow the coding please help and solve my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJvy1.jpg)

Comment: What solutions have you already tried?

Comment: You need to provide your own code or proof that you've tried to achieve what you want on your own. This site isn't designed to give you answers to your problem, but to teach you how to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: I provide the all details i want please read

Comment: @JakeB I,m trying the code but not total salary count nothing so please can you solve how to do